# Symfony2: ESI setMaxAge Cache

Tags: symfony, caching, esi

I have a Controller whose Action is rendered in twig with

`{{ render_esi(controller('MyWebsiteBundle:Element:header')) }}`

The Action itself looks like this:

```
/**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function headerAction()
    {
        $currentLocale = $this->getCurrentLocale();

        $response = $this->render('MyWebsiteBundle:Element:header.html.twig', array(
            'currentLocale' => $currentLocale,
            'myTime' => time()
        ));
        $response->setPublic();
        $response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);

        return $response;
    }
```

When I reload my Browser, the `"myTime"` changes everytime.

How can I use `setShardeMaxAge()`, so that the Twig is only renderd after the MaxAge is expired?

Comment: Do you use `app_dev.php` or `app.php` to access the page ?

Comment: For the moment I use app_dev.php

Comment: Did you enable symfony's internal caching proxy `AppCache` in your `app_dev.php` ([howto?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy)) ?

Comment: require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
// wrap the default AppKernel with the AppCache one
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

Comment: As I see you  have accepted Dan Revah's answer .. just out of curiousity - what part of the answer were you missing?

Comment: I missed the esi: { enabled: true } part! But thank you also!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Symfony2 there's a few things you need to do in order to activate esi caching.

1) In `app/config/config.yml` make sure you activated esi, with a fragments path.

```
framework:
    esi: { enabled: true }
    fragments: { path: /_proxy }
```

2) Wrap the kernel with the AppCache object

```
// web/app.php
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

3) Set up the AppCache configuration

```
// app/AppCache.php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'debug'                  => false,
            'default_ttl'            => 0,
            'private_headers'        => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
            'allow_reload'           => false,
            'allow_revalidate'       => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
            'stale_if_error'         => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

About your issue if it is caching your response and the only problem is that it's reloading every time you refresh the page. make sure the configuration `allow_reload` property is set to false.

You can read more about it here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html