# Symfony : kernel->loadClassCache and multiple render controller

Tags: php, symfony, caching

A little question about cache and render controller.

I use `$kernel->loadClassCache()` in my `app.php`, to activate the app cache. So it seems to work, my site is now very fast :).

Now I want to have a wallpaper displayer, on each refresh I want to show another wallpaper, each time. But seems impossible with the very strong cache of symfony.

To display my wallpapers, i use a render controller, like this

```
{{ render(controller("SiteBundle:Sidebar:sidebarWallpapers")) }}
```

Is it a way to never cache this render part ? Or set a very short cache time ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to activate ESI cache to work with default Symfony app cache : [Symfony2: ESI setMaxAge Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614573/symfony2-esi-setmaxage-cache)